# sql - ignore duplicates while joining

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables.
Table1 is 1591 rows. Table2 is 270 rows.

I want to fetch specific column data from Table2 based on some condition between them and also exclude duplicates which are in Table2. Which I mean to join the tables but get only one value from Table2 even if the condition has occurred more than time. The result should be exactly 1591 rows.

I tried to make Left,Right, Inner joins but the data comes more than or less 1591.

Example
Table1

```
type,address,name
40,blabla,Adam
20,blablabla,Joe
```

Table2

```
type,currency
40,usd
40,gbp
40,omr
```

Joining on 'type'
Result

```
type,address,name,currency
40,blabla,name,usd
20,blblbla,Joe,null
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Which currency should be displayed in case there are multiple ones?

Comment: This is a faq. But you need to google a clear staement of what you want. You want one value per group or max value per group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it has to work

```
select *
from
Table1 h
inner join 
(select type,currency,ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by type order by 
currency) as rn
from 
Table2
) sr on
sr.type=h.type
and rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's standard SQL, therefore, it should work on your rdbms system.

```
select * from Table1  AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS y ON t.[type] = y.[type] and y.currency IN (SELECT MAX(currency) FROM Table2 GROUP BY [type])
```

If you want to control which currency is joined, consider altering Table2 by adding a new column active/non active and modifying accordingly the `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [outer apply](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) if it's supported.

```
select a.type, a.address, a.name, b.currency
from Table1 a
outer apply (
    select top 1 currency
    from Table2
    where Table2.type = a.type
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

I typical way to do this uses a correlated subquery.  This *guarantees* that all rows in the first table are kept.  And it generates an error if more than one row is returned from the second.

So:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.currency
        from table2 t2
        where t2.type = t1.type
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as currency
from table1 t1;
```

You don't specify what database you are using, so this uses standard syntax for returning one row.  Some databases use `limit` or `top` instead.